# Virtualenv for different version of django

Tags: python, django

I want to use different django version. how can i create django virtualenv. Please help.

Comment: env.py -c Env_Name
pip isntall Django

python manage.py runserver

Comment: I needed virtualenv created via env.py.

Comment: -1 too for the lasiness. Not that this kind of question should not be on SO, cause it should. Be really, virtualenv step by step installation is complete and easy to understand. The guy didn't even read it.

Comment: You didn't understand, the way which is written in answer 2 everybody can find anywhere, but i needed virtualenv created via env.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need virtualenv and pip. write in shell:

for debian:

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

for fedoras(python 2.4, change if you have another version):

```
yum install python-setuptools
cd /tmpwget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-0.6.3.tar.gz#md5=0602fa9179cfaa98e41565d4a581d98c
tar -xzf pip-0.6.3.tar.gz
cd pip-0.6.3
/usr/bin/python2.4 setup.py install
```

next:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

next:

```
mkdir enviroments # folder for your different virtual environments

cd enviroments # go to new folder

virtualenv --no-site-packages django1.3 # create folder with new django

cd django1.3 # go to this folder

source bin/activate # activate environment

pip install Django==1.3 # install django 1.3
```

check Django version (in shell too):

```
python  

import django

django.get_version() # you should get '1.3.0 final' 

quit()
```

now you can run your server.

quit from virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

delete environment:

```
rm -r ./bin && virtualenv --clear
```

for example, you want to install MySQLdb module for your environment:

```
cd enviroments # go to your environments folder

source django1.3/bin/activate # activate it

pip install django1.3/ MySQL-python # install module
```

Comment: Be aware the `-E` flag is being removed.

Comment: @bradley.ayers what's the new syntax going to be? do you have a link?

Answer (score 8):

Create your virtualenv:

```
virtualenv myenv
```

Activate that virtualenv:

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Install Django:

```
pip install Django
```

Run your project:

```
python manage.py runserver
```